# Express session - Add and access custom cookie field outside of req in a react app

Tags: reactjs, express, express-session

I have a react app that uses express session. The standard session and cookies work as expected but I am trying to add a custom field outside of a req context as below.

```
import session from 'express-session';

export default ({ children }) => {
  
  console.log("session.darkState at top ", session.darkState);//check whats stored when refreshed
  const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState(session.darkState?session.darkState:false);

  function giveMeTheme(darkStateFromAppBar) {
    setDarkState(darkStateFromAppBar);
    session.darkState = darkState;//store in session
    console.log(session.darkState);
  }
```

I am not able to use req context so I am simply using session.....

`session.darkState` goes back to undefined when user navigates to another page or refreshes.

How to store a field for the length of the session?

I use mongo store and when user logs in, I am saving all standard fields such as resave, saveUninitialized in mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution to add custom cookie with express session so ended up using react-cookie

```
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

import NameForm from './NameForm';

function App() {
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['name']);

  function onChange(newName) {
    setCookie('name', newName, { path: '/' });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <NameForm name={cookies.name} onChange={onChange} />
      {cookies.name && <h1>Hello {cookies.name}!</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```